# Evaluation of a polynomial in SciLab

Tags: polynomial-math, scilab

Could you please help me find a mistake in my code?
I need to calculate the polynomial, with parameters the vector and the value of the variable.
I am not allowed to use the power sign (^)
I have got this code but it doesn't work and I don't see what I am doing wrong.

```
function f=veelTermEvaluatie(V,x)
        f=V(1);
        for i=2:length(V)
            for j=0:i-1
                if j=0 then x=x
                    else x=x*x
                end
                f=V(i)*x
            end
        end
    endfunction

    V=[1 2 3 4 5 6]
    x=3
```

Comment: Since the code is so far away from polynomial evaluation, please explain in abstract terms what exactly you want to compute. `f=sum(i=1 to n) V(i)*x^(i-1)` or `f=sum(i=1 to n) V(i)*x^(n-i)` or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first refactored your code, to remove the j=0 situation, since this does not change anything since `x=x` it can be skipped by starting at j=1. I also added some debug printing :

```
function f=veelTermEvaluatie(V,x)
    f=V(1);

    for i=2:length(V)

        printf("\nI: %d --> ", i)            
        for j=1:i-1                
            x = x * x
            printf("j: %d, x=%d ",j,x)
        end

        f=V(i)*x
    end

    return f
endfunction
```

After that it became clear that you multiply the same x, each and every time:

```
I: 2 --> j: 1, x=9 
I: 3 --> j: 1, x=81 j: 2, x=6561 
I: 4 --> j: 1, x=43046721 j: 2, x=-501334399 j: 3, x=0 
I: 5 --> j: 1, x=0 j: 2, x=0 j: 3, x=0 j: 4, x=Inf 
I: 6 --> j: 1, x=Inf j: 2, x=Inf j: 3, x=Inf j: 4, x=Inf j: 5, x=Inf
```

What also happens is that you update the value of f to the highest term, disregarding any other terms.
I think your meaning is to return all terms

So you should create a local x which is reset for every term.

### Working example

```
function f=veelTermEvaluatie(V,x)

    //Initialize the result to be a copy of the input
    f=V;

    // For each element in the input (except the first)
    for i=2:length(V)

        printf("\nI: %d --> ", i);
        //Initialize a local x variable to the global x
        new_x = x;

        for j=1:i-1
            // Update only the local x                 
            new_x = new_x * x;
            printf("j: %d, x=%d ",j,x);
        end

        // Multiply the value in the array with the local x value
        f(i)=V(i)*new_x;
    end

    return f
endfunction

V=[1 2 3 4 5 6]
x=3

result = veelTermEvaluatie(V,x)

disp(result)
disp(sum(result))
```

Comment: This still seems wrong in terms of "evaluate the polynomial with coefficients V at x". The returned array is not the value of the polynomial.

Comment: The proposed code is extremely ugly and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Scilab has already a `horner` function so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. For example, to evaluate the polynomial `1+2*x+4*x^2+8*x^3` at `x=-1,0,1` you can proceed as follows:

```
p = poly([1 2 4 8],'x','coeff')
pval = horner(p,[-1 0 1])
```

which yields the following output

```
--> p = poly([1 2 4 8],'x','coeff')
 p  = 
            2    3
   1 +2x +4x  +8x

--> pval = horner(p,[-1 0 1])
 pval  = 

  -5.   1.   15.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is implement the Horner scheme.

```
f=V(n)
for i from n-1 down to 0 do
    f = f*x
    f = f+V(i)
end for
return f
```

In the question, you return the array of values V(i)*x^(2^i), in the previous answer, the array of evaluated terms V(i)*x^i is returned, but the value of the polynomial is the sum over those terms.

Please elaborate on the input format. Is V an array with index range 1:n? What is the intended relation between index and degree?